# sparkR: how to create a dummy column from character vector?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, grepl

Consider the following simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:4), climate=c("cold_rainy","coldSunny","rainywarm","sunny_warm"))
head(df)

       id    climate
       1     cold_rainy
       2     coldSunny
       3     rainywarm
       4     sunny_warm
```

I can simply create a dummy for all rows containing the word 'sunny' as follows:

```
df$sunny=grepl('sunny',df$climate, ignore.case = TRUE)*1
head(df)

  id    climate        sunny
  1     cold_rainy     0
  2     coldSunny      1
  3     rainywarm      0
  4     sunny_warm     1
```

How could I implement this operation on a SparkDataFrame in sparkR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first transform your string values to lowercase, and consequently use `rlike()` to look for `"sunny"` in `$climate`. The boolean output we consequently `cast()` to type `integer`.

```
ddf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)  # Data
ddf$climate <- lower(ddf$climate) # Convert to lowercase
ddf$sunny <- cast(rlike(ddf$climate, "sunny"), "integer") # Create integer column

> ddf
  id    climate sunny
1  1 cold_rainy     0
2  2  coldsunny     1
3  3  rainywarm     0
4  4 sunny_warm     1
```

Comment: Perfect solution for me, really nice!